# How to send message to mobile Bluetooth device and Arduino device using my bluetooth application

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, arduino

I have create listView of Paired bluetooth devices.I want to send a message or command to Arduino or other bluetooth devices just click on button "Ok". I am posting my method. please give me any solution.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            /*
             * TextView txt = (TextView) arg1;
             * Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" +
             * txt.getText().toString(), 1000).show();
             */
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
            final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    // get user input and set it to result
                                    // edit text
                                    // result.setText(userInput.getText());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Action Found",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();

        }
```